# Face disappearing when imported to Unity (Not Normals)

Tags: modeling, mesh, export, normals, unity

I have search through multiple threads for an answer to this, but I can't seem to fix it. I am having a problem where a face in my model is disappearing upon being imported to Unity. I checked my normals, and the face's normal is going the right way. I have attached the .blend file. Any help is appreciated! The face not showing up is the left eye when you are looking at it from the front. Thank you!

[.blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1YJ1tGgKrF3RWhGQWlVSFRSc2s/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting it to an FBX file, and then importing it into Unity. It worked for me, and it seems like the .blend import is broken somehow.